# Type alias for generic with known parameter

Tags: typescript, generics, antd

I'm writing an AntD form. Is there a way to shorten the form component name with type, like this:

```
const CustomForm = Form<LongTypeName>
const CustomFormItem = CustomForm.Item

const Bar = () => (
  <>
    <CustomForm />
    ...
    <CustomFormItem />
  </>
)
```

I'm using AntD 4.24.7, TS 4.1.2.

Comment: Does your example not work? It works with both functions and classes for me [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAWwJ4HECmZMCcYQBi408YAPACoB8AFAIa4DmAXIpQJSIDeAsAFCIhiXJighcSRkwDcAgL4CBEBAGcoiegBsY9VVhz4IiALwoM2PAWKRYCcmBDIARnmpL+KsOpGZVILQ0zbV19SyNaAFYOOU81DWB6GC1TTR09AysIWgAiAHUACzg4AAdVHJjEAHoqxABBZidsDThgRChUEsxEAHJ1fDAmHsQYVUQwOA09VRgmMHpnLW6oOEQSxnpkMTxEVvbO7p7HFzwejwgtafqqah4PRX5leMQADVS6hydXXGpYp+8pqkcAB3V60So1NKqVbAuC4ADWY2AcMQF2mfiAA)

Comment: Thanks for the link & example. I don't know there's such a handy playground. After bisecting, I found the min working version is TS 4.7. Release note for [Instantiation expression](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-7.html#instantiation-expressions) gives me exactly what I want. Thanks!

Comment: If you found your solution, please post an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the hint of @slava-knyazev I find that the code only works in TS 4.7+. It is a feature called [Instantiation expression](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-7.html#instantiation-expressions).